# C-array as property in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am programming for iOS, and using ARC.

I am trying to use a c-array as property, but it reports error.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *mappingTable[70][254];
```

The error is `"Property cannot have array or function type NSString *[70][254]"`. How can I solve this problem? How can I declare c-array as property?

*Note:*
This is a two dimensional array, I think it is much easier to just use c-array, so I didn't use NSArray for it.

Comment: You can't declare c-arrays as properties. That's what the message says and it isn't lying.

Comment: you should use `NSArray` or declare pure c++ array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare it in that format.  As the error message states you can't use C-style arrays  in property declarations.

The new shorter syntax for arrays makes NSArray and NSMutableArray less of a pain.  Instead of

```
[array objectAtIndex:3]
```

you can simply use

```
array[3]
```

I think in the long run the benefit of using Objective-C objects will outweigh the comfort of using C-style arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Surprised this hasn't been suggested already but you can store the c-array in an NSData object. I just used this method to store an array of frames.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSData *framesArray;


// Create and initialize your c-style frames array
CGRect frames[numberOfFrames];
...
self.framesArray = [NSData dataWithBytes:frames length:(sizeof(CGRect) * numberOfFrames)];


// To Access the property
NSUInteger arraySize = [self.framesArray length] / sizeof(CGRect);
CGRect *frames = (CGRect *) [self.framesArray bytes];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can not declare `c/c++` arrays as properties, you could either use `objective-c NSArray/NSMutableArray` for property or you could declare c++ array.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSArray *mappingTable;
```

or declare pure c style character array like this

```
char mappingTable[70][224];
```

Comment: OK, thanks! Then I declare the NSString array as public variable. It works now!

Answer (score -1):

If you are only going to use it as a private property of the class. Then keep it simple.
skip the YourClass.h file. And write it directly in the YourClass.m file like this.

```
//YourClass.m file


#import "YourClass.h"

@interface YourClass()

@property (strong,nonatomic)NSArray *mappingTable;

@end

@implementation YourClass
@synthesize mappingTable;
@end
```